# How to make a fixed footer modal with scrolling content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.6 in my Angular App, I have a modal which become full-screen on mobile devices, here i would add a fixed footer with scrolling body content.

I've tried to set the modal-content height to 100%, set margins of footer height to modal-body, but I still can't achieve the content scrolling behind the footer...

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

The part with Quantità and other stuff is the footer and here is my modal code:

```css
.modal-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .modal-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

@mixin modal-fullscreen() {
  padding: 0 !important; // override inline padding-right added from js

  .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
  @include media-breakpoint-down($breakpoint) {
    .modal-fullscreen#{$infix} {
      @include modal-fullscreen();
    }

    .btn#{$infix}-block {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ngb-modal-window role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" class="d-block fade modal modal-fullscreen-sm show">
  <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <app-modal-product-content _nghost-cio-c135="">
        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="modal-header">
          <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="">
            <h4 _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="modal-title text-truncate">CAFFE</h4>
          </div><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="button" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span _ngcontent-cio-c135="" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div>
        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="modal-body">
          <ngb-accordion _ngcontent-cio-c135="" role="tablist" class="accordion" ng-reflect-close-other-panels="true" ng-reflect-destroy-on-hide="false" ng-reflect-active-ids="panel-aggiunte" aria-multiselectable="false">
            <!--container-->
            <div class="card ng-star-inserted">
              <div role="tab" class="card-header" id="panel-aggiunte-header"><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="button" ngbpaneltoggle="" class="accordion-toggle ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ngb-panel-toggle="" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panel-aggiunte"><div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" ngbpaneltoggle="" class="aggiunte-title"><strong _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block mb-2">AGGIUNTE</strong><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block mb-0">Aggiungi ingredienti alla tua pietanza</label></div></button>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}-->
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="collapse show ng-star-inserted" id="panel-aggiunte" aria-labelledby="panel-aggiunte-header">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="aggiunte-container ng-star-inserted">
                    <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="row">
                      <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 col-sm-12 affiancato ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-check"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="custom-constrol"><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> BACON + 1,00&nbsp;€ </label></div>
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block attributi"><span _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="badge badge-success mr-2 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(2, 128, 2);"> CON LIEVITO MADRE </span><span _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="badge badge-success mr-2 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(130, 128, 130);"> APROTEICO </span>
                          <span _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="badge badge-success mr-2 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(155, 204, 2);"> BIO </span>
                          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 col-sm-12 affiancato ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-check"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="custom-constrol"><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> OLIVE VERDI DENOCCIOLATE </label></div>
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block attributi">
                          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 col-sm-12 affiancato ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-check"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="custom-constrol"><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> POMODORACCI </label></div>
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block attributi">
                          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 col-sm-12 affiancato ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-check"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="custom-constrol"><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Ghiaccio </label></div>
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block attributi">
                          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 col-sm-12 affiancato ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-check"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="custom-constrol"><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> PROSC. COTTO </label></div>
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block attributi">
                          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 col-sm-12 affiancato ng-star-inserted">
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-check"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="custom-constrol"><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Limone </label></div>
                        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block attributi">
                          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark float-right mb-3 ng-star-inserted"> Step successivo </button>
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}-->
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
            </div>
            <div class="card ng-star-inserted">
              <div role="tab" class="card-header" id="panel-note-header"><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="button" ngbpaneltoggle="" class="accordion-toggle ng-star-inserted collapsed" ng-reflect-ngb-panel-toggle="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel-note"><div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" ngbpaneltoggle="" class="aggiunte-title"><strong _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block mb-2">RICHIESTE</strong><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="d-block mb-0">Aggiungi le tue richieste</label></div></button>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}-->
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="collapse ng-star-inserted" id="panel-note" aria-labelledby="panel-note-header">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="form-group w-100 ng-star-inserted"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="">Note</label><textarea _ngcontent-cio-c135="" maxlength="250" class="form-control text-area-varianti ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-maxlength="250" ng-reflect-model=""></textarea></div>
                  <button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark float-left mb-3 ng-star-inserted"> Step precedente </button>
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "6"
}-->
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}-->
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
            </div>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}-->
          </ngb-accordion>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="modal-footer">
          <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="row w-100">
            <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-12 mb-3"><label _ngcontent-cio-c135="">Quantità</label>
              <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="input-group group-qta ml-md-auto">
                <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="input-group-prepend"><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="btn btn-outline-dark" disabled=""> - </button></div><input _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="number" disabled="" class="form-control qta">
                <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="input-group-append"><span _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="input-group-text">pz</span><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="btn btn-outline-dark"> + </button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-4 align-self-center">
              <h5 _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="font-weight-bold float-left my-auto"> 19,90&nbsp;€ </h5>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-cio-c135="" class="col-8"><button _ngcontent-cio-c135="" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right"> Aggiungi al carrello </button></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </app-modal-product-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</ngb-modal-window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a fixed height for modal body and make modal body scrollable. Then add your content inside that.

Eg:

```
.modal{ height: 100vh; width: 100%;}
.modal-header{ height: 20vh;}
.modal-footer{ height: 20vh;}
.modal-body{ height: 60vh; overflow-y: auto}
```

above will give viewport height (100vh) to modal and then 20vh height to both header and footer, then gives remaining 60vh to modal body. That makes it fully packed. Now content inside body will scrolls optionally. That fill give you sticky footer and header.